# Django-ldap authentication issue: user DN/password was rejected by ldap server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, ldap

I am receiving the below (on django console) although i am entering the right password. I am guessing it's an issue with `DN`. However, couldn't understand what is wrong as i am searching for user with uid at `dc` level, with all the sub-trees in scope (2), that returns an object.

> search_s('dc=zl,dc=local', 2, 'uid=%(user)s') returned 1 objects: cn=abler bill,ou=credit,ou=zltest,dc=zl,dc=local
> Authentication failed for abill: user DN/password rejected by LDAP server.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this. I seem to be having the same challenge.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. No i have not got any solution. There is a change in priority, hence it's not on my current list. Will update with any solution if i get it in future.